# Code to find any prime number not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7, primes

I wrote this python code to find any prime number, the 1st, 2nd, 1000th, etc. I ran the code and it returned this, no matter what integer I entered:

```
2 is the 1 prime
3 is the 2 prime
5 is the 3 prime
7 is the 4 prime
```

Here is the code (written in python 2.7.8):

```
 #code to find the nth prime
def isprime(n):
    '''check if integer n is a prime'''
    # make sure n is a positive integer
    n = abs(int(n))
    # 0 and 1 are not primes
    if n < 2:
        return False
        # 2 is the only even prime number
    if n == 2:
        return True
        # all other even numbers are not primes
    if not n:
        return False
        # range starts with 3 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n for all odd numbers
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
num_ofprimes = 0
candidate_prime = 2
final_primes = raw_input("What prime would you like to find?")
while num_ofprimes <= final_primes:
    if isprime(candidate_prime) == True:
        if candidate_prime == 2:
            num_ofprimes = num_ofprimes + 1
            print (str(candidate_prime) + " is the " + str(num_ofprimes) + " prime")
            candidate_prime = candidate_prime + 1
            #2 is prime
        elif candidate_prime % 2 == 0:
            candidate_prime = candidate_prime + 1
            #if a number is even it is not prime
        else:
            num_ofprimes = num_ofprimes + 1
            print (str(candidate_prime) + " is the " + str(num_ofprimes) + " prime")
            candidate_prime = candidate_prime + 1
            # checks all odd numbers to see if prime then prints out if true
print ("All done!")
```

Comment: Try `int(final_primes)`...

Comment: Why aren't you doing that `candidate_prime % 2 == 0` check in your `isprime` function?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice catch, but shouldn't that rather result in an infinite loop?... Ah, it is. the program is not terminating, but running infinitely after 7.

Comment: @tobias_k that was just the first error I saw, the more I look...

Comment: What happens if `isprime(candidate_prime)` doesn't evaluate to `True` in your while loop?

Comment: This might also be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/1639625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not stop after it found those first few primes, but it runs into an infinite loop, generating no more output. The reason for this is that if your `isprime` check fails, you never increment the `candidate_prime` variable!

Also, as noted in comments, you should compare `num_ofprimes` to `int(final_primes)`; otherwise you are comparing an `int` to a `str`, which is much like comparing apples to oranges.

Finally, you should put the check whether the number is even inside your `isprime` function. Not only will this make your `isprime` function actually return correct results for even numbers, but it will also make your code a whole deal more compact, as you no longer need all those `if/elif/else` blocks below your `if isprime` check.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tobias's important comments, you seem to be doing a lot of extra work in your script for no reason. The `while` loop can be simplified to:

```
while num_ofprimes < final_primes:
    if isprime(candidate_prime):
            num_ofprimes = num_ofprimes + 1
            print (str(candidate_prime) + " is the " + str(num_ofprimes) + " prime")
    candidate_prime = candidate_prime + 1
```

Comment: But only if the even-number-check is moved to `isprime` instead.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, good point. I changed the `not n` condition in the function to `n%2!=0` in my version of the script and forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in range(3, 1000):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include some text which explains how the code answers the question or solves the problem in addition to bare code.